# Ball contained in a convex cone

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space.
Let $C\subset X$ be a closed convex cone with nonempty interior.
We denote by $B_X$ and $S_X$ the unit ball and the unit sphere of $X$ respectively.
Let $e\in C\cap S_X$, $\mathcal{E}>0$ and $\delta>0$. Then, I have to prove that

$$\delta \mathcal{E} B_X\subset C-\delta e.$$

---

Note 1: $A-x:=\{a-x\,:\, a\in A\}$.

Note 2: A cone is a set that $\lambda C+\mu C=C$ for every $\lambda,\mu>0$ and $C\cap(-C)=\{0\}$.

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have the definition of a cone correct?  See, for example, http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~jtropp/notes/Tro00-Cone-Theorem.pdf.

Comment: I think it is equivalent. Nevertheless, here there is another
http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/fpta/2009/609281.pdf

Comment: Suppose $C$ contains two distinct $v_1$ and $v_2$.  Then, according to your definition, $v_1-v_2=0$, i.e. $v_1=v_2$.  Thus, the only $C$ that satisfy your definition are singletons.  Are you sure you didn't mean $C\cap (-C)=\{ 0\}$?

Comment: Ah, that was a mistake. True.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: let $C$ be the quadrant $x,y\ge0$ in the plane. Let $e=(1,0)$. The set $C-e$ does not contain the origin as an interior point.